# How to resolve connection refuse issue of database when hosting jboss web application in amazon

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jboss

I have created amazon ec2 instance and rds instance correctly. I deployed my war file to the ec2 correctly and it deployed when I run the jboss server using Putty. But the mysql data tables does not created and it says connection refuse error. What are the changes that should include in standalone.xml? I will attach my datasource in standalne.xml below.

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/iasDs" pool-name="iasDs_pool" enabled="true">
                <connection-url>
                    jdbc:mysql://localhost.com:3306/ias_db
                </connection-url>
                <driver>
                   mysql
                </driver>
                <pool>
                    <max-pool-size>
                        30
                    </max-pool-size>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>
                        ****
                    </user-name>
                    <password>
                        ******
                    </password>
                </security>
            </datasource>               
            <drivers>               
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>   
            <drivers>
```

End point of the rds is  my-db-instance.cty4r97dlgx0.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306.Help me with this.

Comment: Start the database. It isn't running. Or else correct the IP address or port to agree with where it is running.

Comment: I change some informations but did not work sir.I need to know what is the correct way.can you give me an example or good link to refer.Buecause I have tried many ways but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

change your `<connection-url>` to use the RDS end point instead of localhost

I assume localhost is the default but you have the database on RDS on a different
address

The username and password will also need setting correctly for the RDS instance

If that doesn't work you need to check

1) security groups on the RDS and network ACLs for your VPC

2) basic connectivity on port 3306 between RDS and EC2.  For example on the EC2 run the command `nc -vz my-db-instance.cty4r97dlgx0.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306`

3) try connecting to the RDS from the EC2 with a command line client mysql

Comment: I changed the '<connection-url>' as follows 'connection-url>
                    jdbc:mysql://my-db-instance.cty4r97dlgx0.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/ias_db
                </connection-url>' but still the same erro.Do I need to install mysql server in specific place from putty or what should I do.

Comment: I solved the problem thank you for your help.I create a new user and granted permmision then that username and password was added to the standalone.xml file.the connection url should be ' connection-url> jdbc:mysql://my-db-instance.cty4r97dlgx0.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/i‌​as_db </connection-url>'